# difflib.SequenceMatcher on more than two sequences

Tags: python

My end result: I need a variant of zip_longest() which, given an arbitrary number of sequences, yields them side by side, filling the gaps with None whenever they're not identical.

The parallel when working with files is when you type
vimdiff file1, file2, file3, ....

For example, given the sequences

```
a = ["foo", "bar", "baz", "asd"]
b = ["foo", "baz"]
c = ["foo", "bar"]
```

I need a function that yields these tuples:

```
"foo", "foo", "foo"
"bar", None, "bar"
"baz", "baz", None
"asd", None, None
```

I managed to achieve it quite simply using difflib.SequenceMatcher. However, it only works for exactly two sequences:

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

def zip_diff2(a, b, fillvalue=None):
    matches = SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).get_matching_blocks()
    for match, next_match in zip([None] + matches, matches + [None]):

        if match is None:
            # Process disjoined elements before the first match
            for i in range(0, next_match.a):
                yield a[i], fillvalue
            for i in range(0, next_match.b):
                yield fillvalue, b[i]
        else:
            for i in range(match.size):
                yield a[match.a + i], b[match.b + i]

            if next_match is None:
                a_end = len(a)
                b_end = len(b)
            else:
                a_end = next_match.a
                b_end = next_match.b

            for i in range(match.a + match.size, a_end):
                yield a[i], fillvalue
            for i in range(match.b + match.size, b_end):
                yield fillvalue, b[i]
```

How do I get it to work on an arbitrary number of sequences?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you want I think it is necessary to create a **base sequence** first with all possible values among the given sequences. To do that I did the code:

```
def build_base_sequence(*sequences):
    # Getting the biggest sequence size.
    max_count = 0
    for sequence in sequences:
        max_count = max(max_count, len(sequence))

    # Normalizing the sequences to have all the same size.
    new_sequences = []
    for sequence in sequences:
        new_sequence = sequence + [None] * max_count
        new_sequences.append(new_sequence[:max_count])

    # Building the base sequence:
    base_sequence = []
    for values in zip(*new_sequences):
        for value in values:
            if value is None or value in base_sequence:
                continue
            base_sequence.append(value)

    return base_sequence
```

Than you can make use of your function, calling it multiple times. I think the usage of `difflib.SequenceMatcher` is too complicated so I did my own code:

```
def zip_diff(*sequences):
    base_sequence = build_base_sequence(*sequences)

    # Building new sequences based on base_sequence
    new_sequences = []
    for sequence in sequences:
        new_sequence = [None] * len(base_sequence)
        for value in sequence:
            new_sequence[base_sequence.index(value)] = value
        new_sequences.append(new_sequence)

    # Now let's yield the values
    for values in zip(*new_sequences):
        yield values
```

It is kind of a *newbie/dummy/naive* code but, hey, it does the trick!

```
>>> a = ["foo", "bar", "baz", "asd"]
>>> b = ["foo", "baz"]
>>> c = ["foo", "bar"]
>>> for values in zip_diff(a, b, c):
...     print values
...
('foo', 'foo', 'foo')
('bar', None, 'bar')
('baz', 'baz', None)
('asd', None, None)
>>>
```

I hope it helps you somehow.

Comment: Thanks, however it has two major limitations: 1. it doesn't support repetitions in the sequences. Every sequence element must be unique. 2. It doesn't behave nicely when there's a tiny difference, then a big subsequence of identical elements. e.g. a="abcdefg"; b="bcdefga". difflib correctly put the substring "bcdefg" side by side, while your code will align "a" and leave everything else misaligned.